# SQL subqueries using SELECTs only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query with subqueries using SELECT and aggregation functions only, e.g.:

```
select distinct m_name
from MANUFACT
where m_id in (select TOP 1 m_id
                from PRODUCT
                where p_id = (select p_id
                              from PRODUCT
                              where p_desc = 'Bronze Sculpture'));
```

The question is about query similar to this one, but using SUM(). The data I have:
Table SPERSON:

```
sp_id | sp_name
---------------
 10   | Jones
 39   | Matsu
 23   | Atsuma
```

Table SALE:

```
sp_id | qty
-----------
  10  |  20
  23  |  30
  10  |  10
  39  |  20
```

etc.

The task is to return the sp_name s whose total number of products is <= 75.

The teacher says *we're not allowed to use join*, but I doubt whether is any way not to use it.
This is what I have so far:

```
select sp_name
from SPERSON
where sp_id in (select sp_id from SALE
    where qty in (select sum(qty) group by sp_id));
```

Anyway, I only got the 'Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference' error, but can't really get the thing.

Comment: You almost have the query correct. Focus on your summation. Pull that logic out and run it by itself. You need to sum qty but you need to filter the rows after grouping. Do that using the HAVING clause. When you have that working, you can then apply it to your current query.

Comment: Suggestion - when you pull that subquery out to work on it, include the value of `sum(qty) as tqty` in the select list so you can SEE the total quantity to verify that your logic is correct. You will, of course, need to remove it when you use it as the subquery.

Comment: I've been giving it a lot of tries, including the result of sum() in select, using having, but the thing is that it just doesn't allow me to use the extracted result of function as a condition in my further steps, and it gives me the same error:
select sp_name
from SPERSON
where sp_id in (select sp_id from SALE
     where qty in (select sum(qty) as qtyy group by sp_id having qtyy <= 75));

Comment: You are struggling with aggregates - that is the first problem. Until you understand aggregates and the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, you can't really accomplish your goal. Your inner-most subquery is malformed - it does not select from a table. That's the biggest problem. And I give you a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86c969b2a9619e404621373183eef05e) to demonstrate that you don't always need to actually generate an aggregate (as a column in the select list) to be useful.

Comment: Thank a lot! This makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
SELECT q.sp_name
  FROM( SELECT sp_name,
              (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM sale s WHERE s.sp_id = p.sp_id ) AS qty
          FROM SPERSON p
         GROUP BY sp_name
          ) q
 GROUP BY q.sp_name
 HAVING SUM(q.qty) <= 75
```

Mostly, using correlated subqueries, which may contains a reference to the outer query and so produces different results for each row of the outer query, is not suggested. But I suggested to use it as an alternative method depending on your case for **not** being permitted to use *JOIN*. Btw, it is more straightforward to use *JOIN* .

Comment: While this appears to work (4th time is a charm, right), it is terribly written and does not serve as a learning tool. OP is a STUDENT and giving a working answer without explanation does little to teach.

Comment: Anyway, would you mind to try give me the answer about the outer reference of the group by? Didn't get the real cause troubling this error in my case.

Comment: perhaps the value for `sp_id` coming from the outer query would be `null` or `non-matching` the inner , or for some cases you can get too many rows within the subquery (not valid for this case, since it doesn't return multiple rows for the sake of aggregation without group by and returning one column only provided that the SUM aggregation returns a non-null value) @DaryaWiśniewski

Answer (score 1):

You can try to approach a problem from different direction.
Create a query to calculate total quantity grouped by `sp_id`

```
SELECT s.sp_id, SUM(s.qty)
FROM SALE s
GROUP BY s.sp_id
```

Filter persons id which has quantity less or equal to 75

```
SELECT s.sp_id, SUM(s.qty)
FROM SALE s
GROUP BY s.sp_id
HAVING SUM(s.qty) <= 75
```

Because joins not allowed, "inject" name as a subquery

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT p.sp_name FROM SPERSON p WHERE p.sp_id = s.sp_id) AS name
FROM SALE s
GROUP BY s.sp_id
HAVING SUM(s.qty) <= 75
```

Comment: I didn't think about such type of a query, thanks a lot!